# How to separate PHP response you get using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a front page which contains a form with 4 different fields. So far I got this fields posted to my PHP handler. On the PHP side, I have 4 tests and 4 else/if statements for each input fields. The problem is my AJAX code returns one single response for all 4 tests. So I can print this response at the bottom of my front page. What I want is to show 4 separated responses per input field.

HTML:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
    <div>
        <label>
            <span>Item 1</span>
            <select name="TestItem1">
                <option>value1</option>
                <option>value2</option>
                <option>value3</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <span>Item 2</span>
            <input type="text" name="TestItem2">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <span>Item 3</span>
            <input type="text" name="TestItem3">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <span>Item 4</span>
            <input type="text" name="TestItem4">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Check</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

AJAX CALL

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('form').submit( postgonder ) 
    }); 

    function postgonder() 
    {          
        $.post('result.php', $('form').serialize(),function(veri){$('#result').html(veri)}); 
    }
```

PHP:

```
<?
$testitem1=$_POST['TestItem1'];
$testitem2=$_POST['TestItem2'];
$testitem3=$_POST['TestItem3'];
$testitem4=$_POST['TestItem4'];     

$test1 = (some tests of $testitem1);
    if(empty($testitem1)) {
    echo "-";
  }
    else if($test1) {
    echo "successful";
  }
  else {
    echo "failed";
  }
$test2 = (some tests of $testitem2);
    if(empty($testitem2)) {
    echo "-";
  }
    else if($test2) {
    echo "successful";
  }
  else {
    echo "failed";
  }
$test3 = (some tests of $testitem3);
    if(empty($testitem3)) {
    echo "-";
  }
    else if($test3) {
    echo "successful";
  }
  else {
    echo "failed";
  }
$test4 = (some tests of $testitem4);
    if(empty($testitem4)) {
    echo "-";
  }
    else if($test4) {
    echo "successful";
  }
  else {
    echo "failed";
  }
?>
```

My AJAX call returns:
"failed - - -" if the form is empty or "successful successful - -" etc.

Comment: Show us your AJAX call and what you're returning. You may want to put the function return in an array and transmit as JSON

Comment: It's there at the bottom of the first code. Sorry, I should have put it in another code box.

Comment: You're not showing us what is returned

Comment: Isn't it obvious in PHP code? I don't understand? This is all I have here. There are 3 conditions for each test. Depending on the input if the test is passed it returns successful texts.

Comment: What, *exactly*, does the PHP return? You're asking us to show you how to separate the return, so show us the return. It *isn't* obvious from the PHP code. We'd have to run your code to see what is returned.

Comment: @JayBlanchard *It isn't obvious from the PHP code.* - it is obvious :-) PHP return just a string: "failed - - -" :-) It is not obvious to understand what OP want do get :-)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at what you are doing with result from AJAX:

```
function(veri){$('#result').html(veri)});
```

means that you expect php to return some formatted HTML.

Lets format it! Instead of:

```
$test1 = (some tests of $testitem1);
  if(empty($testitem1)) {
  echo "-";
} elseif($test1) {
  echo "successful";
} else {
  echo "failed";
}
```

do:

```
$respArray = [];
$test1 = (some tests of $testitem1);
if(empty($testitem1)) {
  $respArray['test1'] = "-";
} elseif($test1) {
  $respArray['test1'] = "successful";
} else {
  $respArray['test1'] = "failed";
}
```

Do the same transformation for test2, test3, etc..
That way you will collect all responses in array.
And then lets do the HTML output:

```
$html = '';
foreach($respArray as $key=>$status){
    $html.='<p>'.$key.' : '.$status.'</p>';
}
echo $html;
```

Hope this example will bring you some ideas what else you can apply.

Comment: Thanks for your examples, I almost understand how to separate them on PHP. The thing is I still get one single response using my current AJAX code. Again where I put my result div I can print test1: failed, test2: -, test3: -, test4: - all together. My point was to divide these 4 responses into 4 different result divs. So I can put results wherever I want within my HTML code. Sorry, I couldn't explain it well at first.